# Recursive function return None even though print() works

Tags: python, recursion, return

I am trying to return `count` in this recursive function but it always returns None. When I do `print(count)` instead of `return count` it gives me the correct result. Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance :)

```
count = 0


def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    global count
    if low > high:
        return count
    else:
        if s[low] == s[low].lower():
            count += 1
        count_lowercase(s, low + 1, high)
```

Comment: you need to `return count_lowercase(s, low+1, high)`

Comment: you need to return count_lowercase in the last line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `count_lowercase(s, low + 1, high)`, otherwise the function simply ends after executing that statement, resulting in `None` being returned.

```
count = 0


def count_lowercase(s, low, high):
    global count
    if low > high:
        return count
    else:
        if s[low] == s[low].lower():
            count += 1
        return count_lowercase(s, low + 1, high)
```